# Avoid extra query with Mongo and Express in PUT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm updating a record in Mongo with Mongoose/Express:

```
app.put('/loggedIn/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user._id == req.params.id) {
    User.update({
      _id: req.user._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        interests: req.body.interests
      }
    }, function(err, num) {
      if (err) return err;
      User.findById(req.user._id, '_id username interests', function(err, user) {
        if (err) return;
        res.json(user);
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log('fail');
  }

});
```

How can I avoid doing the second query in the callback of the `update()`, seems a lot just to return the newly updated document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're always updating only one document you can use [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) (or findOneAndUpdate), which updates the document if found and returns it to the callback:

```
app.put('/loggedIn/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user._id == req.params.id) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {
      $set: {
        interests: req.body.interests
      }
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) return;
      res.json(user);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('fail');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the raw Mongo response as the 3rd update callback argument. Check if this contains what you want. Otherwise, try passing the option { raw: true }.

See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) instead of a separate find and update.

Answer (score 0):

I also sometimes do User.Find() and then inside the success callback Doc.save(). That lets you do more complex things between if it's not just a straight update from the request.